# Virtualized appdata in non-packaged app

Tags: desktop-bridge

I have DAC converted app. On first launch it copies one of its EXEs to `localappdata` folder and launches it.

This EXE gets copied into this folder:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\MyApp_z4vxg0xscex6e\LocalCache\Local\MyApp
```

It launches successfully and `GetCurrentPackageId` fails, which means this EXE is not running as Appx app, but is running as a normal Win32 desktop app.

The problem is that I can't get the path to my EXE inside of it. `GetModuleFileName` returns this:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MyApp\myexe.exe
```

`GetFileAttributes` for this path returns -1. `GetCurrentDirectory` returns the same folder.

Is it a bug of `Windows Desktop Bridge` platform? Is there a way to get path to folder in which my running EXE is located?

P.S. Windows 10 Version 1703 (Build 15063.483).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get path to folder in which my running EXE is located?

If `myexe.exe` is copied to the local folder as you descried above then what you just want is to get the local folder path. For this you can get the [local folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder) and then get the path property in UWP as follows:

```
StorageFolder^ storageFolder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
String^path = storageFolder->Path;
```

> GetFileAttributes for this path returns -1

UWP apps do not have permission to access all files on the device. By default, apps can access certain file system locations such as application install directory or application data locations. For more info, please see [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Directly access `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MyApp\myexe.exe` by `GetFileAttributes` may not work. More details please reference [Skip the path](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/).

Comment: I don't call `GetFileAttributes` from UWP app. I call it from app with full permissions.